# What's wrong with my PHP datetime code?

Tags: php, datetime, redirect, if-statement, timezone

I'm not experienced with PHP. I'm loving it so far, except that this bit of code is working sometimes and other times not at all.

I'm trying to redirect based on the time of day. I have this script set up on multiple domains, with different times for each. Sometimes it works correctly, and sometimes it does not. I have modifed my php.ini file as well as .htaccess to try and set the timezone. I have tried writing the time in CST which my server is in(Hostgator), but no luck there either. I should note that there is some HTML that follows my code here, but it's outside of the php.

It doesn't make sense to me why it only works SOMETIMES. I've tried clearing my browser cache many times but it never helped. In this code, it should only display the html below it between 5:47 PM and 6:43 PM and redirect at all other times, right? Is it some sort of caching issue? Is the script being stored and then not being executed when I visit multiple sites in a row? Any help is greatly appreciated.

The best case scenario is this is only happening to me because I am visiting the sites too much to make sure the script is working correctly. Is that possible?

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$hour = date("G");
$min = date("i");

if(($hour >= "0" and $min >= "00") and ($hour <="17" and $min <= "47"))
    {
    header('Location: http://mysite.php');
    exit();
}
elseif(($hour >= "18" and $min >= "43") and ($hour <="23" and $min <= "59"))
    {
    header('Location: http://mysite.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Your conditions are incorrect. Try manually calculating the results of `15:59` or `19:40`, they will not be what you expect..

Comment: Sorry, but what does that mean? How do I calculate the results of 15:59 and 19:40. I have a solution now I believe, but I still don't understand what was wrong with my code and why it worked intermittently.

Comment: What I meant was, pretend that the time is now `15:59`, that means `$hour = "15"; $min = "59";`. Mentally step through your code and think what happens with every step, how each comparison works, etc.

Comment: Eureka! Thank you. I had this huge comment typed out trying to explain how I don't understand still and in the process figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the shorten code, I converted the time to Military time. If the military time is less than 1747 OR greater than 1843 - it will redirect, else will display the HTML content

```
            date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
            $hour = date("G");
            $min = date("i");
            $milTime = $hour . $min ;

            if($milTime < 1747 || $milTime > 1843)
            {
            header('Location: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/');
            echo "Redirect";
            exit();
            }
            echo "<h1>$milTime Show HTML Content</h1>";
```

Comment: Ok, so far that seems to be working well, plus it's easier to mange too. Thanks! My original code is working at the moment for my other domains, but I'm going to convert to this military time code and hopefully achieve the reliability I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `intval()` to get an actual integer and compare that:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$hour = intval( date("G"), 10 );
$min = intval( date("i"), 10 );

if(( $hour >= 0 and $min >= 0 ) and ( $hour <= 17 and $min <= 47 ))
{
header('Location: http://mysite.php');
exit();
}
elseif (( $hour >= 18 and $min >= 43 ) and ( $hour <= 23 and $min <= 59 ))
{
header('Location: http://mysite.php');
exit();
}
```

What you're doing is comparing **strings**, which are a character-by-character comparison (their order in the ASCII table). So, for example, if you compare `"13" > "10"`, that's correct because `"1" == "1"` (equals, keeps going) and then `"3" > "1"` (true, returns true).

But what if you compare `"098" > "100"`? `"0" > "1"` (false, returns false). Obviously it doesn't work for your purposes, since 098 = 98 **is actually less than 100**.

**EDIT:** As @DCoder correctly mentioned, the strings are first converted to numbers (integers) and then compared. I would highly recommend to make sure to convert them to numbers explicitly and then compare to avoid possible issues when dealing with strings.

Comment: Comparing numbers is more semantically correct, but PHP has a special rule that says [*"If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically."*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Also, you picked a bad example for numerical comparison, `098` does not equal `98`, it's an invalid *octal* number that becomes `0`.

Comment: @DCoder you're right, I should have written `intval( ... , 10);` to specify a base 10 integer. Modified it. One problem with that rule (and that's why I avoid it) is that it says **converted to a number**, which in the docs say it's an `integer`... but in what base? 2, 8, 10, 16? The hour `17` would be in base 10, but `09` in base 8 (octal). As I don't know what will be, I would force 10 and make the comparison in the same base.